# how to get the item from listview to another listview?

Tags: vb.net

How to do this thing i've been struggling with this thing all night long, i want to get the item from the listview to another listview. Like, when i select an item from the list view 1 i can get the total liters of it from the list view 2.

[image]

Comment: How did you populate the first ListView? Think that through...

Comment: I mean, take a look at the code you used to populate the first Listview. You can apply the same concept to grab data from that one and populate the second. I haven't done VB in a good while, so I'm rusty on that.

Comment: you could just as easily run a new query to get the total

Comment: yeah2..i already got that..it just my mind went out of order coz of sleepless night..tnx btw..more power :D